# How do I determine the way an application is terminating using OllyDbg?

Tags: windows, terminate, ollydbg

I am using 32-bit OllyDbg version 2.01 on a Windows application that appears to be terminating (not crashing due to an exception).

Unfortunately, there are a lot of different ways an application can terminate. It can send WM_CLOSE to the main window, or call Exit(), etc. How can I determine using OllyDbg the way the process is terminating?

Answer (score 0):

a simple trace session can yield lots of good pointer

open the exe in ollydbg and hit ctrl+f12 and / or ctrl+f11 asthe case may be
and then look at the trace window (window icon ... three dots) for the last executed instructions    here is a screen shot for an app with ExitProcess Exit

you can profile a single module from the trace record output

[image]